# Como obtener la función que se ha realizado en una consulta SQL (Postgres)

Tags: sql

¿Existe alguna función que me permita saber que operación a realizado el usuario?, es decir, si ha realizado un `Update` o `delete` o `drop`.
Al igual que para saber la fecha actual se usa `NOW()`. Quería saber si hay algo parecido para lo que pido.

Gracias!

Comment: Para eso existe el *log* de transacciones, que debes haber configurado adecuadamente. Puedes leer la [documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/runtime-config-logging.html) para que tengas una idea de lo que puedes hacer. Saludos

Comment: Vael gracias, tambien he hencontrado que se puede hacer mediante la propiedad TG_OP